# OpenMP impact on performance

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a script using openMP, but when I measure the execution time of it (using  `omp_get_thread_num`)  the results are preety odd,

- if I set the number of threads to 2 it measures 4935 us
- setting it to 1 takes around 1083 us
- and removing every openmp directive turns that into only 9 us

Here's the part of the script I'm talking about (this loop is nested inside another one)

```
for(j=(i-1); j>=0;j--){
   a=0;
   #pragma omp parallel
   {    
       #pragma omp single
       {
           if(arreglo[j]>y){
              arreglo[j+2]=arreglo[j];
            }
             else if(arreglo[j]>x){
                  if(!flag[1]){
                     arreglo[j+2]=y;
                     flag[1]=1;
                   }
                arreglo[j+1]=arreglo[j];
                }
             }
             #pragma omp single
             {
                if(arreglo[j]<=x){
                   arreglo[j+1]=x;
                   flag[0]=1;
                   a=1;
             }
      }
    #pragma omp barrier
    }
    if (a==1){break;}
}
```

What could be the cause of this differences? some sort of bottleneck, or it's just the added cost of sychronization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We are *talking* about a really short execution time, which can be easily affected by the environment used for the benchmark;
2. You are *clearly* using an input size that does not justify the overhead of the parallelism.;
3. Your current design only allows for `2` threads; no room for scaling;
4. Instead of using the `single` constructor, you might as well just statically divide those two code branches based upon the thread `ID`, you would *save* the overhead of the `single` constructor;
5. That last barrier is redundant since the `#pragma omp parallel` has already  an implicit barrier at the of it.

Furthermore, your code just looks intrinsically sequential, and with the current design, the code is clearly not suitable for parallelism.

> if i set the number of threads to 2 it measures 4935 us setting it to
> 1 takes around 1083 us and removing every openmp directive turns that
> into only 9 us

With `2` threads you are paying all that synchronization overhead, with `1` thread you are paying the *price* of having the `openMP` there. Finally, without the parallelization, you just removed all that overhead, hence the lower execution time.

Btw you do not need to remove the OpenMP directives, just compile the code without `-fopenmp` flag, and the directives will be ignored.